# Gmail Signatures For Google Workspace Employees

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, gmail-api, google-workspace

I am developing an Google Sheets Add-on and at this point I need to be able to access all employees of the domain and change their Gmail signatures.

I have come across a solution but I find it hard to get the grasp of. Orginal post [here](https://gist.github.com/tholeb/c3775b7e747ea84fcc5febaa41872629) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49784910/googlejsonresponseexception-not-found-error-when-using-gmail-api-sendas-patch-m)

Below is a code that as suggested should make my life easier.
However, I am concerned with the service account and the authentication.
As I understand every addon user would have to generate those on their own and I would like to do it automatically via Google App Script.

*Those lines I am uncertain of*

- `var OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY  = '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n';`
- `var OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_EMAIL = 'xxx@yyy.iam.gserviceaccount.com';`

As a super admin on google workspace I am trying to update employees signatures but can't do it without wide-domain delegation and service account.

*Code*

```
// these two things are included in the .JSON file that you download when creating the service account and service account key
var OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY  = '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n';
var OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_EMAIL = 'xxx@yyy.iam.gserviceaccount.com';


function getDomainWideDelegationService(serviceName, scope, email) {

  Logger.log('starting getDomainWideDelegationService for email: ' + email);

  return OAuth2.createService(serviceName + email) 
      .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
      // Set the private key and issuer.
      .setPrivateKey(OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY)
      .setIssuer(OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_EMAIL)       

      .setSubject(email)      
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
      .setScope(scope);

}
```

Additionally I couldn't find any appropriate documention addresing my question.
Can you share anything with me or clarify my doubts?

I can share more info if you need.

Comment: If you want to access every user in your domain then your going to have to use a service account with domain wide delegation.   If you want to access one user at a time then you can use Oauth2.

Comment: Ok, that is something new to me. I will check it.

Comment: Tho I am still not sure how it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out. After publishing the add-on the service-account has all the privilages by default.